# Check if a user ever had subscription in Android

Tags: android, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I have an Android application with subscription. How can I know that a user had ever used the subscription or the trial period?

Comment: Please check Android Developer docs https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions and also Google console provide to trails feature Subscription and free trial time periods
Weekly trai
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for